# Changing Fabric App Identifier from Code(Swift iOS)

Tags: ios, swift4, google-fabric

For Android in Fabric, there is an option to change the app Identifier while building the Fabric instance. I want to use this functionality for separating analytics based on User role(like Employer,Customer ...).

Following is the code in Android:

```
Fabric.Builder builder = new Fabric.Builder(ApplicationGlobal.getContext())
                .appIdentifier(BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".employer")
                .kits(new Crashlytics());
        Fabric.with(builder.build());
```

Here as soon as login, based on the role fabric is built.

In iOS there is no Builder class for achieving this. How to provide app Identifier to Fabric in runtime in iOS?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks! Right now Fabric only respects the bundle ID of the app at build time. You will need to build and distribute with different bundle IDs.